# Elegant Reflection in Python?

Tags: python, reflection

I have a small number of different Python classes (each standing for a different kind of strategy) and numerous configurations (e.g. parameters) for them. Currently I have organised the configurations in json files, which may look like this:

```
{
 "script": "xyz.strategy.strategyA",
 "datafile": "//datasrv10//data$//data//bloom.csv",
 "assets": ["B EQUITY","A EQUITY"],
 ... 
}
```

So, I have to use some sort of reflection to initialize the correct class. I found importlib for that purpose. I managed to import modules. Now each script is its own module and each module has a build function with the same interface:

```
def build(configuration, data):
    return Risk(configuration, data)


class Risk(Strategy):
```

All of this looks like bad old-school Java to me. Can anyone show me the light in Python?

Comment: Where should the light shine? Remove the build function, initializing the class (or instance?), each class has its own module, Is there a fix number of classes? is there a fix number of files? is class <=> json (one class per json)? Do the build functions look the same? Is the import a problem? From the code you show I can not generalize to many classes/files - that is the reason for the questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need some sort of configuration for this setup then there is no silver bullet. You can use json, yaml or maybe a relational database to store the configuration. Some improvement could come from allowing python code to be used for config, but this creates security issues if configuration can be provided externally.

The second step is translating configuration into actual python class instances, assign correct parameters etc. `importlib` serves great for this purpose and there isn't much to be improved upon here. You need some kind of factory for your classes, just try not to abstract too much (this is very Java-like and not pythonic), maybe one global method that is able to create objects based solely on configuration fragment?